# Stuck and need another pair of eyes. Return value from decimal

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-debugging

Been banging my head on this for a bit. Working on a smart contract and have things working except this last piece. Basically a number is generated (ex. 111), this number is used in Uniswap as a decimal point.(3434.111). Ethereum then converts this 3434.111 number to the long number 334111000000000000000.

I have the below code that checks this number and I am trying to grab the 111 from this long number. With the below code I am able to grab it only if the last 15 digits are zeros. If the number is 334111000000000000001, or any other number outside of 0 in those last 15 digits it fails.

Any help is much appreciated. have tried everything.

```
function getNumber(uint256 number) private pure returns (uint256) {
    uint256 decimals = 18;

    uint256 numberAfterDecimals = number % (10**decimals);

    uint256 checkDecimals = 3;

    while(checkDecimals < decimals) {
        uint256 factor = 10**(decimals - checkDecimals);
        //check if number is all 0s after the decimal math
        if(numberAfterDecimals % factor == 0) {
            return numberAfterDecimals / factor;
        }
        if(numberAfterDecimals % factor != 0) {
        uint256 extraNumberAfterDecimals = numberAfterDecimals % factor;

        return numberAfterDecimals - extraNumberAfterDecimals;
        }
        checkDecimals++;
    }

    return numberAfterDecimals;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand you want the first 3 decimal places from the number you put into the function. If that is the case you do not need the while, the following will do.

```
function getNumber(uint256 number) public pure returns (uint256) {
    
    uint256 decimals = 18;
    uint256 checkDecimals = 3;
    uint256 factor = 10**(decimals - checkDecimals);
    uint256 numberAfterDecimals = number % (10**decimals);
    return numberAfterDecimals/factor;
  
  }
```

Consider that memory allocation is expensive, you could do a one liner for less gas:

```
function getNumber(uint256 number) public pure returns (uint256) {
  
    return (number % (10**18))/(10**(15));
  
  }
```

Quick note, I made the function public to test it in Remix but private should also work

Comment: That did it! Worked like a charm. Thank you! Much appreciated!